# @ModelAttribute and BindingResult behavior

Tags: spring

I have created two classes A and B. Class A has a method calculate

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String calculate(
            HttpServletRequest request,
           PlanVO planVO,
            BindingResult result,
            Map<String, Object> model) throws ParserConfigurationException, 
                        SAXException, IOException {
validator.validate(planVO, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {           
            model.put(PLAN_VO, planVO);
            return "test";
        }
```

Class B also has the same method with same parameters as shown below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String calculate(
                HttpServletRequest request,
                PlanVO planVO,
                BindingResult result,
                Map<String, Object> model) throws ParserConfigurationException, 
                            SAXException, IOException {
    validator.validate(planVO, result);
            if (result.hasErrors()) {           
                model.put(PLAN_VO, planVO);
                return "test";
            }
```

When I am running the code, class A validates the inputs and test.jsp is opened. On test.jsp errors are being displayed using `<spring:errors path="*"/>`.

If i do the same for class B, it validates the input populate the BindingResult object and response goes to test.jsp. but I am not able to see the errors.

Also if I update the method signature in class B as `@modelAttribute("planVO") PlanVO planVO,` it starts working as shown below.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public String calculate(
                    HttpServletRequest request,
                    @ModelAttribute("planVO") PlanVO planVO,
                    BindingResult result,
                    Map<String, Object> model) throws ParserConfigurationException, 
                                SAXException, IOException {
        validator.validate(planVO, result);
                if (result.hasErrors()) {           
                    model.put(PLAN_VO, planVO);
                    return "test";
                }
```

Now I want to ask why class A is not asking for this @ModelAttribute or why class B is asking for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share the code of class B too

Comment: where is the PLAN_VO constant defined? is it global or per controller?

Comment: yes, I am just adding @ModelAttribute in the method signature and it starts working...No change...